# Display Exception error message in Zend Form - Zend Framework 2

Tags: exception, zend-form, zend-framework2

I wanted to display a simple exception message in zend form which is thrown by an exception. I check whether there is a duplicate record existing in the database and if exits then I want to throw an error saying the the record with that name already exists in the database. This I wanted to show in the add.phtml file exactly after the record name textfield.

This is how I am trying to do:

In my Controller:

```
public function addAction()
{
    try {
        $records->validateDuplicateRecords($recordTitle);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //doing all the stuff like saving data to database
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage(); //Not sure with this part
    }
}
```

And the class where I am checking for duplicate records:

records.php

```
public function validateDuplicateRecords($recordTitle)
{
    //fetching all titles from database

   //comparing with $recordTitle using foreach and if
   //all these here in the loop works, I am giving the skeleton of my code
    foreach($records as $record)
    {
        if($record == $recordTitle) {
            throw new \Exception("Record with title '$recordTitle' already exists");
        }
        return true;
    }   
}
```

So that is basically how im doing, I know how this try and catch works with pure php stuff, but I don't know how I can use the exceptions with Zend Framework 2 and zend forms. In case if anybody has a solution for this would be glad if it can be shared.

P.S. I followed the Album Module so basically my structure resembles more or less same from the official Module

**EDIT**: add.phtml has been addded

add.phtml

```
<?php
$title = "Add New Record Title";
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>

<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute("action", $this->url("addRecordTitle", array('controller' => "album", 'action' => "add")));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('recordTitle'));
echo $this->formInput($form->get('submit')); 
echo $this->form()->closeTag($form); 
?>
```

Comment: Do you just want to know how to attach an error message to your form, or do you have problems with your validation, too?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to attach error message to my form, my validation works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your example, a way to do it would be this. However i suggest you read yourself into the inbuilt validators [Db\RecordExists and Db\RecordNoExists](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#db-recordexists-and-db-norecordexists), as they may already do what you're trying to do.

```
public function addAction() 
{
     $form = $this->getForm(); //theoretical

     try {
         $records->validateDuplicateRecords($recordTitle);
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
         $form->setMessages(array(
             'recordTitle' => array($e->getMessage())
         ));
         return new ViewModel(array(
             'form' => $form
         ));
     }

     if ($form->isValid()) { 
         //usual stuff
     }
}
```

With this code you'd attach the error message onto your `title`-FormElement, be sure to edit the name into the name of your title element.

Comment: you mean to say that I don't need to explicitly echo the exception message in my add.phtml, please do clarify on this part. In case if I need to echo it in add.phtml, can you show how I can do that. Thanks

Comment: one more information needed, do I need to use any errorMessage class in my controller. Right now I am not using any and just doing this stuff `catch (\Exception $e)`. So please do throw some light on this and I have tried the way you have suggested, alas not working, right now I am not echoing any error messages in my add.phmtl, please do clarify on this as well.

Comment: Please provide your add.phtml so i can see how you have set up your view, cuz my code should get you running :) But if i see your view i may be able to help out more (in 2 hrs)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am adding my add.phtml file, please do go through it and suggest the necessary changes which i need to make. Thanks for your time and effort

Comment: I've just slightly editted the `recordTitle` into my example. You should be able to understand my code so far and if an entry exists, the exception should be thrown. And if that happens, the error gets attached to your form and will be displayed. No need to manually echo anything. If you need more help on that, i suggest you post your FULL `addAction()` and Form + Validation up somewhere. Errors could be on so many different places

Comment: thanks for your effort, this works now, as you mentioned there was a minor error in my validation part. Answer accepted :)